# Filtering pandas dataframe column of numpy arrays by nan values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame

```
    ID    Unique_Countries

0   123     [Japan]
1   124      [nan]
2   125    [US,Brazil]
.
.
.
```

I got the Unique_Countries column by aggregating over unique countries from each ID group. There were many IDs with only 'NaN' values in the original country column. They are now displayed as what you see in row 1. I would like to filter on these but can't seem to. When I type

`df.Unique_Countries[1]`

I get

`array([nan], dtype=object)`

I have tried several methods including

`isnull()` and
`isnan()`

but it gets messed up because it is a numpy array.

Comment: Lets try `df.Unique_Countries.str.contains('nan')`

Comment: @wwnde it just lists every row with a `NaN` next to it. It does that if I try `.contains('US')` instead of `.contains('nan')` as well

Comment: I cant quite understand what you need. I thought all you needed is to select from the outcome of your intitial operation. If you need to drop and remain with those that are not `nan`, try `df[~df.Unique_Countries.str.contains('nan')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cell has `NaN` not in 1st position, try use `explode` and `groupby.all`

```
df[df.Unique_Countries.explode().notna().groupby(level=0).all()]
```

OR

```
df[df.Unique_Countries.explode().notna().all(level=0)]
```

---

Let's try

```
df.Unique_Countries.str[0].isna()  #'nan' is True

df.Unique_Countries.str[0].notna()  #'nan' is False
```

To pick only non-nan-string just use mask above

```
df[df.Unique_Countries.str[0].notna()]
```

Comment: I don't think it's either. Your answer returned False for every row. I say I don't think its a string because when I type `df.unique_countries[0]` it gives me `array(['US'], dtype=object)` where there are quotations around US

Comment: could you share output of this command:  `type(df.Unique_Countries[1][0])`

Comment: i think we're getting somewhere. It says it's a float

Comment: that did the trick! I figured it was just a weird type of NaN - thanks a lot!

Comment: wait real quick - this answer would only work if nan is the first value of the array. Is there something I could add to make it work if it wasn't the first? i.e. [Australia, nan]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answers based on string method `contains` would fail if a country contains the substring nan in it.

In my opinion the solution should be this:

```
df.explode('Unique_Countries').dropna().groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(list)
```

This code drops nan from your dataframe and returns the dataset in the original form.

I am not sure from your question if you want to dropna or you want to know the IDs of the records which have nan in the Unique_Countries column you can use something similar:

```
long_ss = df.set_index('ID').squeeze().explode()
long_ss[long_ss.isna()]
```